# Magit: how remove push branch?

Tags: magit, git

I want to remove the push branch for a repository. I only use merge branch to push to a remote repository and now I have two headers with the same info all the time:

```
Head:     master Merge pull request #zzz in xxxxxxx from yyyyyyyyyy to master
Merge:    origin/master Merge pull request #zzz in xxxxxx from yyyyyyyyyy to master
Push:     origin/master Merge pull request #zzz in xxxxxx from yyyyyyyyyy to master
```

The adding of a push branch was a mistake but I don't know how to remove it.

Comment: I don't know how to do this in Magit (to be honest, I don't know how to get into this situation in Magit), but you can always edit the `.git/config` file, where this information is available in plain text.

Answer (score 7):

Bring up the magit status window with `M-x` `magit-status` or whatever shortcut key binding you use. type `b` to bring up the branch menu. type `p` to cycle through the push options enough times to get to `default:remote.pushDefault` and your extra line should go away.